# How to ssh in, start top, and close ssh session with a custom ~/.toprc

Tags: bash, ssh, top, nohup

If I log into my remote host via ssh and run top, it picks up the ~/.toprc configuration file. I can also run the following command successfully

```
ssh -t <user>@<host> "top -b > top.dat"
```

However, this keeps the ssh session open forever. I want to use an ssh session to start a top batch process and exit the ssh session. The issue I'm having is everything I've tried either doesn't work or doesn't pick up the ~/.toprc configuration file.

Here is what I've tried:

```
ssh <user>@<host> "top -b > top.dat &"
ssh -f <user>@<host> "top -b > top.dat"
ssh -f <user>@<host> "nohup top -b > top.dat &"
ssh <user>@<host> "nohup top -b > top.dat &"
ssh -f <user>@<host> "nohup top -b > top.dat"
```

All with the same results of not picking up ~/.toprc

```
ssh -t <user>@<host> "top -b > top.dat &"
```

Top exits when the ssh session is closed (immediately)

```
ssh -ft <user>@<host> "top -b > top.dat"
ssh -ft <user>@<host> "nohup top -b > top.dat &"
ssh -ft <user>@<host> "nohup top -b > top.dat"
```

Does not pick up ~/.toprc and complains that pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Top says it will read $HOME/.toprc. I have verified that $HOME is set in all of these cases and that $HOME/.toprc exists. What is different about these two methods that is causing the asynchronous calls to not pick up the configuration file?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

Here is my toprc

```
top's Config File (Linux processes with windows)
Id:i, Mode_altscr=0, Mode_irixps=1, Delay_time=1.0, Curwin=0
Def fieldscur=�������ķ���&')*+,-./012���������FGHIJKLMN��QRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghij
    winflags=193840, sortindx=18, maxtasks=0, graph_cpus=0, graph_mems=0
    summclr=1, msgsclr=1, headclr=3, taskclr=1
Job fieldscur=�����(��Ļ�@<��)*+,-./012568>?ABCFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghij
    winflags=193844, sortindx=0, maxtasks=0, graph_cpus=0, graph_mems=0
    summclr=6, msgsclr=6, headclr=7, taskclr=6
Mem fieldscur=���<�����MBN�D34��&'()*+,-./0125689FGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghij
    winflags=193844, sortindx=21, maxtasks=0, graph_cpus=0, graph_mems=0
    summclr=5, msgsclr=5, headclr=4, taskclr=5
Usr fieldscur=�����������)+,-./1234568;<=>?@ABCFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghij
    winflags=193844, sortindx=3, maxtasks=0, graph_cpus=0, graph_mems=0
    summclr=3, msgsclr=3, headclr=2, taskclr=3
Fixed_widest=0, Summ_mscale=0, Task_mscale=0, Zero_suppress=0
```

**EDIT 2**

Sorry... Both machines are not Redhat 7. I wasn't thinking when I said that. I'm sshing from a Redhat machine into a machine running yocto-linux using a dropbear ssh server. I just tested out openssh too. It's probably the ssh server in the yocto recipes that are causing the issue. I just tested Redhat to Redhat and sure enough it does work.

Comment: ssh -ft host -l user "nohup top -b > top.out" worked fine on a debian9 hosts.
it read ~/.toprc. 
what does your toprc look like?

Comment: @RaoufM.Bencheraiet Just added my toprc file. See edit 1. I should also not that I am logging in as the root user.

Comment: I didn't think to ask this : what happen if you login normally and instead of running top run 'top -b' compare with the output of top, what I think is happening is that the -b flag is disabling a lot of stuff from tops output/input.

Comment: @RaoufM.Bencheraiet 'top -b' works when I ssh in and run the command manually. Sorry, I misspoke earlier about Redhat -> Redhat. See Edit 2.